# Error with CAST SQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, casting

I am trying to combine two expressions and display them as a header. Displaying them as a header isn't the problem, combining the two lines is what's holding me back.

I am using the expression:

```
CAST(Max((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS DECIMAL (10,4)) + SPACE(10) +
   CAST(@InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS DECIMAL (10,4))
```

I tried using `INT NUMERIC`and `FLOAT` as well. The only one that didn't return an error was float but that messed up the numbers.

I am trying to get an output like this

```
Cost: $10,000                                     Shrink: 120
```

Whether I use or don't use `CAST` I get the error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

I can provide my full code if needed.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

You try to concatenate numeric and string:

This is a numeric:

```
CAST(Max((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS DECIMAL (10,4)) +
```

This is a string: [show official documentation of SPACE function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950(v=sql.90).aspx)

```
SPACE(10) +
```

This is a numeric:

```
CAST(@InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS DECIMAL (10,4))
```

If you want to use only string please cast using varchar instead of decimal(10,4)

in this way:

```
CAST(Max((@PurchaseCost + @Prod_CostLBS) * @InputWeight) AS VARCHAR) +
SPACE(10) +
CAST(@InputWeight - SUM(Sum([IC_ProductLots].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])) OVER () AS VARCHAR (10,4))
```

Comment: That displays it without error, however the cost is a money value and I would prefer it to have the '$' before it and it also applies many zeros. That's why I was trying to use DECIMAL, so I could keep the format of the numbers.

Comment: So you can try to apply an internal CAST to DECIMAL(10,4) so apply an external CAST to VARCHAR

Comment: I am sorry but I don't really follow. What exactly is an external CAST vs internal CAST?

Comment: @Austin: I create this Sql Fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/777d0/2/0 I don't understand want you want exactly